# Help on SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Suppose I have 3 tables

**t1**

```
Nid   name
1    aaa
2    bbb
3    ccc
```

**delT1**

```
Nid    name
```

**t2**

```
Sid    Nid     value
1      1       AAA
2      1       BAC
3      2       CSA
```

In table `t1` `Nid` is primary key which is foreign key for `t2`

Now what I want is when I delete value from `t1` it automatically deletes all values from `t2` where `t1.Nid=t2.Nid` and a value of deleted `t1` get inserted into `delT1`

How can I create a trigger for this type of task?

Please help me since I am new to sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the FK in T2 to be `ON DELETE CASCADE`:

```
ALTER TABLE T2 DROP CONSTRAINT FK_T1_Nid; <-- your constraint name here
ALTER TABLE T2 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_T1_Nid FOREIGN KEY (Nid)
   REFERENCES T1 (Nid) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Then create a trigger on T1 to push the information to delT1:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_T1_D ON T1 FOR DELETE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT delT1
SELECT Nid, Name
FROM Deleted;
```

Note this trigger prevents you from using an OUTPUT clause on DELETEs against T1. [BOL says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx):

> If the OUTPUT clause is specified without also specifying the INTO keyword, the target of the DML operation cannot have any enabled trigger defined on it for the given DML action. For example, if the OUTPUT clause is defined in an UPDATE statement, the target table cannot have any enabled UPDATE triggers.

Comment: @gbn Yeah losing text off the right is a problem, especially on mobile.

Answer (score 4):

A normal trigger wouldn't work: the foreign key would give an error before the code runs.

What you can do is set a [CASCADE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973.aspx) on your foreign key so a delete in T1 will delete from T2 automatically.

Personally, I'd use a stored proc and transaction to delete from T2 first, then T1.

Comment: good call, I didn't think through what the poster was actually trying to accomplish and the constraint tossing an error

Comment: @lazyDBA: yep, easily forgotten. And y'know, I can't remember if a before/INSTEAD OF trigger would work... ;)

Answer (score 2):

@gbn has the preferred way to go. Since you asked for a trigger, you could do this for comparison's sake:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t1_Delete ON t1
INSTEAD OF DELETE AS BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT INTO delT1 (Nid, name)
  SELECT Nid, name
  FROM DELETED;

  DELETE FROM t2
  WHERE t2.Nid IN (SELECT Nid FROM DELETED);

  DELETE FROM t1
  WHERE t1.Nid IN (SELECT Nid FROM DELETED);
END;
```

Comment: You forgot to add `INSERT INTO delT1 ...`

Comment: @Andriy M - Yes, I sure did - thank you. Edited to include the delT1 table.