# How to know if a row in a table is being referenced in other tables before deletion?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I have lookup table, whose records are being referenced in other tables. For example, a countries lookup table, and a user table referc the country id from countries table.

I want to know, how i can get count of references and all the rows in other tables, which have a record with a country id.

If a reference of a row is found anywhere else, i need to show an alert to user that this record is being referened, and cannot be deleted, and list down all the referenced rows in a grid.

I have seen a similar topic at

[SQL Server: how to know if any row is referencing the row to delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301968/sql-server-how-to-know-if-any-row-is-referencing-the-row-to-delete)

But the answer didn't helped at all, and gave an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname = 'YourTable'

DECLARE @Command VARCHAR(MAX) 

SELECT @Command = isnull(@Command + ' UNION ALL ', '') + 
       'Select count(*) ,''' + SCHEMA_NAME(obj.schema_id)+'.'+OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id) + ''' '+
       'From ' + SCHEMA_NAME(obj.schema_id)+'.'+OBJECT_NAME(fkc.parent_object_id) + ' '+
       'Where ' + col.name+ ' IS NOT NULL' 
from sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
INNER JOIN sys.columns col on fkc.parent_object_id = col.object_id and fkc.parent_column_id = col.column_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects obj ON obj.object_id = col.object_id
where object_name(referenced_object_id) = @TableName

execute (@Command)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give reference as a foreign key, then sqlserver easily help you by [Viewing dependensy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190624.aspx) and you just select query to [get all table](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/04/sql-server-get-the-list-of-object-dependencies-sp_depends-and-information_schema-routines-and-sys-dm_sql_referencing_entities/)

```
select * from countrytable where countryid in
(select countryid from usertable )
```

or

```
select * from countrytable  c
inner join usertable u on c.countryid = u.countryid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge like

```
 Merge countrytable  as c
using usertable as t on t.cid = c.cid
when not matched then delete
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also one more efficient way

```
 ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

If a row is referenced it will throw an error that it is refernced by other table which is your exact requirement.

Comment: I'm afraid that you missed a point in question that my requirement was to know in advance if there are any references to current rows, I do not want to handle the SqlException - but show an alert if the row is being referenced in some other tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the references using this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Countries C
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Users U WHERE U.CountryID = C.CountryID)
```