# TSQL i need help by transforming sql statement in function

Tags: sql, database, function, t-sql

with the following statement i get the result (after small changes id, table name ...)

```
declare @RowId int = 1 declare @TableName sysname = 'ParentTable'

declare @Command varchar(max) 

select @Command = isnull(@Command + ' union all ', '') + 'select ''' +
object_name(parent_object_id) + 
    ''' where exists(select * from ' + object_name(parent_object_id) + ' where ' + col.name+ ' = ' + cast(@RowId as varchar) + ')'  from
sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
    join sys.columns col on fkc.parent_object_id = col.object_id  and fkc.parent_column_id = col.column_id

where object_name(referenced_object_id) = @TableName

execute (@Command)
```

i want to transform this statement in tsql function

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Dynamic SQL, @Stu . Dynamic SQL ***cannot*** be used in a function. Period.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) and you want a "one size fits all" function; that isn't how SQL works. Write your SQL for what you need; and you don't "need" a *do anything* function. If you're needing to go down dynamic SQL like this, that suggests you have an underlying design flaw.

Comment: @Larnu I realise that :) possibly dynamic sql is not necessary but with no explanation of the requirement, who knows?

Comment: None of us, that's for sure @Stu . :)

Comment: like this example. i want only to get if user are not referenced to delete them:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301968/sql-server-how-to-know-if-any-row-is-referencing-the-row-to-delete

Comment: An interesting challenge. create a function to obtain a list of child tables with FK references to a given parent table and ID. Although it is not possible to include dynamic SQL in the function, it may be possible to dynamically generate a function to handle all cases for a given schema. That function could be generated once and used as needed until the schema changes. At that point, it would need to be regenerated.  Stay tuned...

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not possible to include dynamic SQL in a function, it is possible to dynamically generate a function to handle all cases for a given schema.

Below is some SQL that can generate a static function definition with logic to check all foreign keys. Once generated, this function can be used as needed until the schema changes. At that point, it would need to be regenerated.

```
--  SQL to generate a function that will identify all tables having an
--  FK reference to a specific parent table and key value.
--  Assumptions:
--  1. All PKs are of the same specified type. For multiple types, separate functions may be generated.
--  2. Primary and foreign keys are single columns.

-- Settings
DECLARE @FunctionName sysname = 'fn_ForeignKeyReferences'
DECLARE @PrimaryKeyDataType sysname = 'int' -- int, uniqueidentifier, ... other type from sys.types

-- Additional generated settings
DECLARE @GeneratedDateTime NVARCHAR(50) = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), GETUTCDATE(), 20)
DECLARE @NoTablesFoundMessage NVARCHAR(100) = '-- No tables with specified PK type "' + @PrimaryKeyDataType + '" were found'
DECLARE @CharKeyTypeSuffix NVARCHAR(10) = CASE WHEN @PrimaryKeyDataType LIKE '%char%' THEN '(max)' ELSE '' END

-- Table to hold FK table and column data
DECLARE @FkInfo TABLE (
    ForeignKeyName sysname,
    ParentSchemaName sysname, ParentTableName sysname, ParentColumnName sysname,
    ChildSchemaName sysname, ChildTableName sysname, ChildColumnName sysname
)

-- Gather FK information
INSERT INTO @FkInfo
SELECT fk.name, ps.name, pt.name, pc.name, cs.name, ct.name, cc.name
FROM sys.foreign_keys fk
JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
-- parent (primary key) schema/table/column
JOIN sys.tables pt ON pt.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
JOIN sys.schemas ps ON ps.schema_id = pt.schema_id
JOIN sys.columns pc
    on pc.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
    and pc.column_id = fkc.referenced_column_id
-- Chile (foreign key) schema/table/column
JOIN sys.tables ct ON ct.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
JOIN sys.schemas cs ON cs.schema_id = ct.schema_id
JOIN sys.columns cc
    on cc.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
    and cc.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id
JOIN sys.types t ON t.user_type_id = pc.user_type_id
WHERE t.name = @PrimaryKeyDataType
ORDER BY ps.name, pt.name, pc.name, cs.name, ct.name, cc.name

-- Diagnostic preview
--SELECT * FROM @FkInfo

-- SQL templates (Drop function)
DECLARE @DropFunctionTemplate NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.objects
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].[<functionName>]'')
    AND type IN ( N''FN'', N''IF'', N''TF'', N''FS'', N''FT'' )
)
BEGIN
    DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[<functionName>]
END
'

-- SQL templates (Create function)
DECLARE @FunctionTemplate NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
-- Function to identify all tables having an FK reference to a specific parant table and key value
-- Generated: <GeneratedDateTime>
CREATE FUNCTION [<functionName>](
    @SchemaName sysname,
    @TableName sysname,
    @RowId <PrimaryKeyDataType><CharKeyTypeSuffix>
)
RETURNS @ReferencingTables TABLE (SchemaName sysname, TableName sysname)  
AS      
BEGIN    
    IF 1 = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Noop INT  -- Syntactic placeholder
    END
<ParentTablesSql>

    RETURN
END
'

-- SQL templates (Code to search for FK references to one particlar parent table)
DECLARE @ParentTableTemplate NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
    ELSE IF @TableName = ''<ParentTableName>'' AND @SchemaName = ''<ParentSchemaName>''
    BEGIN
        INSERT @ReferencingTables
        SELECT SchemaName = '''', TableName = '''' WHERE 1 = 0  -- Syntactic placeholder
<ChildTablesSql>
    END'

-- SQL templates (Code to search for FK references from one particlar child table and FK)
DECLARE @ChildTableTemplate NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
        UNION ALL SELECT SchemaName = ''<ChildSchemaName>'', TableName = ''<ChildTableName>'' WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [<ChildSchemaName>].[<ChildTableName>] T WHERE T.[<ChildColumnName>] = @RowId)'

-- Pull it all together, substituting schema, table, and column names as we go 
-- and concatenating intermediate results using the XML PATH('') trick.
DECLARE @GeneratedSql NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        @FunctionTemplate
        , '<GeneratedDateTime>', @GeneratedDateTime)
        , '<functionName>', @FunctionName)
        , '<PrimaryKeyDataType>', @PrimaryKeyDataType)
        , '<CharKeyTypeSuffix>', @CharKeyTypeSuffix)
        , '<ParentTablesSql>', ISNULL(pts.ParentTablesSql, @NoTablesFoundMessage))

    FROM (
        SELECT ParentTablesSql = REPLACE((
            SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                @ParentTableTemplate
                , '<ParentSchemaName>', ParentSchemaName)
                , '<ParentTableName>', ParentTableName)
                , '<ChildTablesSql>', cts.ChildTablesSql)
            FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT fk.ParentSchemaName, fk.ParentTableName
                FROM @FkInfo fk
            ) p
            CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT ChildTablesSql = REPLACE((
                    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                        @ChildTableTemplate
                        , '<ChildSchemaName>', fk.ChildSchemaName)
                        , '<ChildTableName>', fk.ChildTableName)
                        , '<ChildColumnName>', fk.ChildColumnName)
                    FROM @FkInfo fk
                    WHERE fk.ParentSchemaName = p.ParentSchemaName AND fk.ParentTableName = p.ParentTableName
                    ORDER BY fk.ChildSchemaName, fk.ChildTableName, fk.ChildColumnName
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ), '&#x0D;', CHAR(13))
            ) cts
            ORDER BY p.ParentSchemaName, p.ParentTableName
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), '&#x0D;', CHAR(13))
    ) pts
)

-- Generate drop sql also
DECLARE @DropFunctionSql NVARCHAR(MAX) = REPLACE(@DropFunctionTemplate, '<functionName>', @FunctionName)

-- Combine for final output
DECLARE @AllSql NVARCHAR(MAX) =
    @DropFunctionSql + 'GO' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    + @GeneratedSql + 'GO' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

--PRINT @AllSql
SELECT CAST('<root><![CDATA[' + @AllSql + ']]></root>' AS XML) -- If the above is too long to "print".

-- Optional direct execute (must run as two separate executions).
--EXEC sp_executesql @DropFunctionSql
--EXEC sp_executesql @GeneratedSql
```

If this is not suitable, you will probably have to code something up in a stored procedure that can generate and execute dynamic sql on-the-fly based on the current schema.